# Как отследить нажатие клавиши в Python , если нажаты ещё какие-либо клавиши?

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, python-3.6

Раньше использовал библиотеку `keyboard` для отслеживания горячих клавишей - быстро и удобно. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что отслеживание не работает, если нажата какая-либо другая клавиша.

Посоветуйте альтернативу, или подскажите, как сделать отслеживание хоткея если нажаты другие клавиши на этой библиотеке?

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я решил эту проблему xD

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('R', start)
keyboard.add_hotkey('R + W', start)
keyboard.add_hotkey('R + A', start)
keyboard.add_hotkey('R + S', start)
keyboard.add_hotkey('R + D', start)
keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
```